# iOS UITableViewCell selected background view cover image on cell issue

Tags: ios, uitableview

I currently developing an iOS APP that has a table whose cell contains an image.
And I set the selected background view to an UIBlurEffectView, when the cell is selected, its text labels can normally show up but the image does not.
Here is the screenshot before selection:
[image: before selection]

Here is the screenshot after selection:

[image: after selection]

Here is the codes setting the selected background view of cell:

```
let backgroundViewVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light))
backgroundViewVisualEffectView.frame = cell.bounds
cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundViewVisualEffectView
```

Here is the codes adding the image to the cell:

```
let contentImageView = UIImageView()
contentImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
cell.contentView.addSubview(contentImageView)
contentImageView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentImageView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentImageView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -cell.bounds.width/40))
contentImageView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentImageView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: 1.5 * cell.bounds.height))
contentImageView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentImageView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentImageView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

Why the image can not show up like text labels when I selecting the cell, any solutions?Thx

Comment: can u post the code please

Comment: What is the image, why is it just white?

Comment: I do not really load the image yet, just put an image view there for testing @Wain

Comment: @nischalhada I just added the codes

Comment: With a background colour only?

Comment: @Wain yes, with a background colour only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the cell is selected it goes through subviews and makes the backgrounds clear so that the selection doesn't show artifacts. So, your issue is your test. Add an image to the image view and it should probably be fine.